# How to set up two dimensional tab in Semantic-ui?

Tags: semantic-ui

I have a semantic-ui tab inside another tab and i am trying to navigate the user directly inside the secondary tab. Here is an example

```
     <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
         <a class="item custom-item" data-tab="first">First</a>
     </div>
     <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="first">
           <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
              <a class="item" data-tab="sub-first">sub First</a>
              <a class="item" data-tab="sub-second">sub Second</a>
           </div>

         <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="sub-first">
             <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
             <a class="item" data-tab="first">sub First</a>
         <a class="item" data-tab="second">sub Second</a>
         <a class="item active" data-tab="third">sub Third</a>
         </div>
         </div>

         <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="sub-second">
             <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
             <a class="item" data-tab="first">sub First</a>
         <a class="item" data-tab="second">sub Second</a>
         <a class="item active" data-tab="third">sub Third</a>
         </div>
         </div>

     </div>

         // JS
     $('.menu .custom-item').tab({
         history : true
     });

     $('.menu .item').tab({
         history : true
     });
```

The above code will override the parent tab history. I wish to achieve something like this : `www.example.com#first/sub-first`